# Installing IvyDE in marketplace in Juna failed

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy

I installed IvyDE within Eclipse marketplace. Eclipse is Juno version.
I do not see the Ivy jar file within the following location:
Preference>Ant>Runtime>
Contributed Entries
Global Entries

Therefore, it is also not within the following location:
Preference>Ant>Runtime>Types.

Which means when I run a simple build.xml as shown below, it fails with appropriate error:

> testbuildivy.xml:3: Problem: failed to create task or type
>   antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings

```
<project name="test ivy" default="test" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
  <target name="test" description="Test ivy installation">
     <ivy:settings />
  </target>
</project>
```

How should I install the Ivy Eclipse plugin, or what other configuration steps are necessary to get Ant to recognize Ivy within Eclipse?

Attempts

- Add jar to Contributed Entries not possible.
- Checked plugins and features directory, Ivy jar is there.
- Tried eclipse with clean option
  no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Ivy. I reinstalled it through Help>Install New Software rather than through the marketplace. I surmise marketplace was not pulling in all dependencies. It appears additional dependencies were installed this time. clean option was not needed. All worked as expected when MarketPlace not used.